# Python3 open CSV do logic write new csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with a couple hundred rows.

To keep it simple, lets go with these three headers:

```
Asignee, ClientName, Lead

Carl Jr, TestCompany, NO
James, TestCompany, NO
Sarah H, TestCompany, NO
Osvaldo W, OtherCorp, Osvaldo W
Walter Green, OtherCorp, No
Ace Ven, PetDick, No
Dan Marino, PetDick, No
```

So in that scenario in the new file I want this to be written

```
PetDick, No
TestCompany, No
```

And since the others have a lead I don't care about those for this report.

There can be as many rows in the file as there are assignees PER ClientName. 
What I need to do is figure out which ClientNames have NO Lead.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

def createReport():
    with open('/home/origReport.csv', 'rt') as origfile, open('/home/newReport.csv', 'wt') as out:
     reader = csv.DictReader(origfile)
     writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='\n')
     for row in reader:
      if row['Lead'] == 'NO':
       writer.writerow(row["Lead"])

createReport()
```

Which gives me not what I want in terms of output.

```
N,O
N,O
N,O
```

If I try putting this in the script.

```
writer.writerow(row["ClientName","Lead"])
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test2.py", line 15, in <module>
createReport()
  File "test2.py", line 12, in createReport
 writer.writerow(row["ClientName","Lead"])
KeyError: ('ClientName', 'Lead')
```

But also I don't know what AND to add to the if statement.

Essentially I want to find each line where Lead is a NO but also where the ClientName doesn't exist on another row where Lead is a name(or essentially anything BUT a NO). If Lead is NOT a NO for the same ClientName on a different ROW then it should be excluded in this report.

Thanks in advance for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
writer.writerow([row["Lead"], row["ClientName"]])
```

`writerow` accepts an array. You got the first output because your input `row["Lead"]` is implicitly converted to `["N", "O"]`;

Comment: Thanks, this worked to get the proper output. Any ideas on the logic.... trying to find the simplest way to do this. But its not coming to me.

Comment: An easy way would be iterating the file two times or reading the files into an object and then iterating through two times. In the first iteration, construction a map<string, bool> to record if a certain clientName with non-NO Lead appears, and in the second iteration utilize the map to complete your logic.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution... not sure how to make a map. Am googling now

Comment: Can you link me to something to get me started on this. I have jumbled up so many loops and stuff im not getting anywhere with it :(

Comment: I cannot give any existing link on this specific issue. Define a dict (map) using `a={}` and in the loop simply say `if is_lead_no(row["lead"]): a[row["clientName"]] = true`. This dict will be used to help you filter out the records you don't want.